# Same logic but have different result with JOptionPane and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Code 1:

```
public static JFrame frame = null;    
public myClass(JFrame frame1)
{
    initComponents();
    frame = frame1;
    String result = JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(
        frame.getContentPane(), "Sample");
}
```

Code 2:

```
public static JFrame frame = null;
public myClass(JFrame frame1)
{
    initComponents();
    frame = frame1;
    sampleMethod();
}

public static void sampleMethod() 
{
    String result = JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(
        frame.getContentPane(), "Sample");
}
```

I wanted the result in Code 1 but the code must look like Code 2. Why do they have different results?

Comment: What do you mean by *"different result"*?

Answer (score 6):

If both pieces of code are relevant, then it is impossible that results are different.
So, this means that the code you provided is not complete enough **or** you are not making clear what you mean with "different result".

And my guess is that you are creating multiple instances of `myClass`, at the same time? I would suggest to try this: (without all that `static`)

```
public JFrame frame = null; // static removed
public myClass(JFrame frame1)
{
    initComponents();
    frame = frame1;
    sampleMethod();
}

public void sampleMethod() // static removed
{
    String result = JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(
        frame.getContentPane(), "Sample");
}
```